# web based admin management for nginx?

Tags: nginx, configuration-management

is there any web base management tool for nginx?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like webmin has a module. Have you looked there as a possible starting point?

Comment: I will :-) http://github.com/vixh/nginx-webmin

Comment: It's at the very least a starting point... Good luck...